# Equations Proof Solvers

Tags: problem-solving

Can Someone solve

$$x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+2020)=1$$

analitically rather than numerically and show me all steps. Also maybe with some preconditions, like only natural solutions, so that it‘s adaptable to diophantine equations, etc.

Thank you all in advance!!!

Comment: A very nice fact seems to be true, only polynomials cubic and quartic being exceptions: all the polynomials $x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots (x+n)=1$ have its $n+1$ roots all real. ¿Is this true for $n\ne 2,3$?

Comment: @Piquito I have added a partial answer. Feel free to give it a try and complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation like $$(x+1) (x+2) (x+3) (x+4) (x+5)\ldots(x+k)=\frac{1}{x}$$ The intersection between the polynomial $y=(x+1) (x+2) (x+3) (x+4) (x+5)\ldots(x+k)$ and the hyperbola $y=1/x$ are exactly $k$ if $k>3$.

This happens because $P_k(x)=(x+1) (x+2) (x+3) (x+4) (x+5)\ldots(x+k)$ has $k$ zeros and
in any interval $(j-1,j);\;j\in\mathbb{Z},j<0$ there is a minimum $\xi_j$ and a maximum $\zeta_{j-1}$ for $j=\ldots,-3,-2,-1$.

**TO DO**

We must prove that the local minima $\xi_j$ have negative values $P(\xi_j)<\frac{1}{\xi_j}$ for $|j|>3$ therefore the curve $y=P_j(x)$ intersects the hyperbola in $|j|$ points for $|j|>3$.

---

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: So it is true. I am too busy in other thing. I hope yourself could finish. Good luck.